# Vmware workstation 4K display support

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-workstation

I have following [Notebook](https://www.digitec.ch/en/s1/product/lenovo-thinkpad-p50-20en-003s-1560-uhd-intel-core-i7-6820hq-16gb-ssd-notebooks-6037224?dclid=CL-cpuuC99YCFfUK0wod-3wCfg&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIkuSf6YL31gIVEBobCh1SMA5NEAQYASABEgLHTvD_BwE) and have the newest vmware workstation pro installed on it.

I created a Ubuntu 17.04 virtual machine and I configure it out, that it displays really slowly on 4K monitor. Almost every time, when I move the mouse, I noticed the mouse pointer delay.

Even sometimes, for example Google Chrome just crash after few minutes. 
Looking at the specification from my laptop, the graphics card memory is 4GB, that is a lot, it should work on 4K display.
The Ubuntu 17.04 virtual machine, following hardware is assigned:

[image]

The main operating system is Windows 10.
Are the settings wrong or what am I doing wrong that is display so slowly on 4K monitor?

Comment: It doesn't matter how much memory your graphics card has. It's probably still an emulated card your VM is seeing and that might be limited. Did you install the VMware tools on your guest?

Comment: Yes I do. The tool works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Increase the processor *core* count (fpr example 6+ on 1 socket) of the guest vm and the system memory (6gb+). Then increase the VM's video memory, try 4GB. You will need a *lot* of memory and raw CPU-Power to run 4k/32bit in a virtual environment (or reduce resolution/color depth). One of your virtual 2d-frames will use 15.6Mbytes of memory (2560*1600*32bit), which has to be moved from your physical ram to your gpu - what does not happen in phy environments. That happens at the cost of Ram, Cache CPU and PCIe.

On my Machine, for example, I use 4K resolution at 3840x2160x32bit(~8.2mp) = 31.6MB. On Phy this takes 240kbyte of memory (because most pixels are done in vram), in VMware Workstation I can see 35Mbyte (of native ram).

A single frame buffer therefore requires more than 32MB to display a 4K image. That thing moving around is causing the delay.

The problem is going to be, how much hardware you can throw on it without any accelerators. Which is the culprit in this case, because video accelerators don't work with VMware Workstation, except native 3d stuff (Settings> Display> Accelerate 3D). CPU-Integrated graphics are limited by their nature and adding a larger card is going to give you a increase in 4k speeds.

Additionally, mobile gpus like in this case are *significantly* slower than the powerful desktop brotherhood. That may cause some of your delay, too.

In my case, I can run a vm on my desktop (2x Xeon E3-1245) *nearly* fluent, but on my Notebook (some i7m stuff, same ram, same ssd) it's super sluggish.